# Derivatives and exponential derivatives quotient operators on two variables

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-operators, derivations

I consider for example the following function of two variables given by
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} \exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m}\exp(\delta_{y})}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{n}$$
Where $\delta_{x}=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\delta_{y}=\frac{d}{dy}$ and $m$ is a positive integer. My question is: when $x < y$ can we write f as
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} \exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m}\exp(\delta_{y})}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{n}=\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} \exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m}\exp(\delta_{y})}g(x,y)?$$
such that $g(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{y}}=\frac{y}{y-x}$. If the formula above is correct can we prove it more explicitly. Precisely, constructing a corollary for which $\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} \exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m}\exp(\delta_{y})}$ is a well-defined operator denoted by $A_{x,y}^{m}$. I need a response, if someone have an idea.

Best regards and thank you.

Comment: $\delta_{x}^{-1} $ is an integral operator. Those usually need a boundary condition? The exponentials are just shift operators.

Comment: for example $\delta_{x}^{-2}T(x)$ is equal to $$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} \int_{0}^{+ \infty}T(x) dx?$$ for $x \in R^{+}$.

Comment: Ok, so your boundary condition is that you start integrating at 0, that's fine. The upper limit of course must be variable - your result must again depend on $x$. So, $\delta^{-2}_{x} T(x) = \int_0^x dx' \int_0^{x'} dx'' T(x'')$.

Comment: Thank you. It is simple to have $\delta_{x}^{m} x^{m}= m!$ But if we have  $\delta_{x}^{-m} x^{-m}$  what can we say in this case?

Comment: If you want to treat something like $x^{-m} $, you should probably use a different boundary condition. How would you integrate $x^{-m} $ starting at $x=0$? That's not well defined.

Comment: x is strictly positive.

Comment: I would like ro find out that $\delta_{x}^{-m} x^{-m} \delta_{x}^{m} x^{m} $ is the identity operator

Comment: "x is strictly positive" doesn't resolve your problem with the ill-defined boundary condition. $\delta_x^{-m} x^{-m} \delta_x^m x^m $ cannot be the identity operator (except for $m=0$), since $x$ and $\delta_x $ don't commute.

Comment: ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To make sense of this, you might Fourier transform
$$A_m=\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} \exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m}\exp(\delta_{y})}=\delta_{x}^{-m} \delta_{y}^{m}e^{\delta_x-\delta_{y}},$$
which would give the operator
$$\hat{A}_m=(k_y/k_x)^m e^{i(k_x-k_y)}.$$
Then $A_m$ acting on a function $f(x,y)$ could be obtained by inverse Fourier transformation,
$$A_m f(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk_x}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk_y}{2\pi}(k_y/k_x)^m \hat{f}(k_x,k_y)e^{i(x+1)k_x+i(y-1)k_y}.$$
The question whether $A_m$ is a well-defined operator would then boil down to whether this integration is well-defined. The function $\hat{f}(k_x,k_y)$ would need to vanish when $k_x\rightarrow 0$ to avoid the pole.

Comment: Firstly, $\frac{\delta_{x}^{-m} exp(\delta_{x})}{\delta_{y}^{-m} exp(\delta_{y})} \neq \delta_{x}^{-m} \delta_{y}^{m} exp(\delta_{x}-\delta_{y})$. Secondly, where those calculations came from? I don't understand your explications.

Comment: Can you give me a reference on this topic?

Comment: $\delta_y$ and $\delta_x$ commute, so you have two commuting operators $A=\delta_x^{-m}e^{\delta_x}$ and $B=\delta_y^{-m}e^{\delta_y}$; the ratio $\frac{A}{B}=AB^{-1}=\left(\delta_x^{-m}e^{\delta_x}\right)\left(e^{-\delta_y}\delta_y^{m}\right)=\delta_x^{-m}\delta_y^{m}e^{\delta_x-\delta_y}$, where in the last step I again used the commutation of $\delta_x$ and $\delta_y$.

Comment: But the operator $e^{- \delta_{y}}= \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \frac{d^{k}}{dy^{k}}}{k!}$ and $\frac{1}{e^{ \delta_{y}}}= \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{\frac{d^{k}}{dy^{k}}}{k!}}$ they are not the same. Can we deduce a commutator here. Is there any propertie that is explaining this formula in a reference?

Comment: $e^{-\delta_y}=\frac{1}{e^{\delta_y}}$, for the reason that for any operator $A$ such that the sum converges one has $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-A)^n/n!\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty  A^m/m!\right)=1$.

Comment: How did you find out this $ (\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (-A)^{n}/n!)(\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} (A)^{m}/m!))=1$?

Comment: it's as simple as $e^A e^B = e^{A+B}$ if $A$ and $B$ are commuting operators; in this case $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-A)^n/n!\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty  A^m/m!\right)=e^{-A}e^A=e^{A-A}=1$, since $-A$ and $A$ commute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting response i understood it. Just a final question can you give me a reference for the commutator relation?

Comment: I have another question $\frac{1}{ exp(\delta_{y}) y^{n}}$ is equal to $exp(-\delta_{y})y^{n}$ or $exp(-\delta_{y})\frac{1}{y^{n}}$? And if $m$ is a positive real number, what can we say in this case?

Comment: the general rule for operator inversion is $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, so $(e^{\delta_{y}} y^{n})^{-1}=y^{-n}e^{-\delta_y}$ --- note the order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129868/discussion-between-adam-hammam-and-carlo-beenakker).